# Sharing a VM with several people

Tags: scripts, virtualbox, virtualization

I "have" some students, which have very varying degree of computer skills, that need to extract some data. To extract these data you'll need to run a couple of python scripts, some bash scripts and use a library. All these scripts has a number of dependencies, and the library is a bit cumbersome to install.

Is it possible that I set up an environment where this works on a virtual machine, and share that virtual machine with my students (so they can install it on their personal computer)?

Answer (score 0):

You can export a virtual machine from VirtualBox as a so called [virtual appliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_appliance) in [UVF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Virtualization_Format) format. Your students then can import those UVF files into their local VirtualBox installations.

You should find the menu items for exporting and importing appliances in the "Files" menu of the VirtualBox Manager.